# JavaScript Array not align

Tags: javascript, arrays

please help me with this.

**Script**

```
<div id="data"></div>
<script>
var data = document.getElementById('data');
var str = '0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,21.16,18.28,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00';
var arr = str.split(',');
var ar = new Array();
for(i=1; i<=arr.length; i++){
    ar.push(i+' ===== '+arr[i]+'<br>');
}
data.innerHTML = ar;
</script>
```

**Result**

```
1 ===== 0.00
,2 ===== 0.00
,3 ===== 0.00
,4 ===== 0.00
,5 ===== 0.00
,6 ===== 0.00
,7 ===== 21.16
,8 ===== 18.28
,9 ===== 0.00
,10 ===== 0.00
,11 ===== 0.00
,12 ===== 0.00
,13 ===== undefined
```

I wanted to take 21.16 and 18.28 to 8 and 9 where the exact value should be.
Why 21.16 is fall in 7 and 18.28 is in 8? it should be in 8 and 9.

Comment: Array index starts at 0 not 1 this is the case I believe in every programming language. So if you count to 8, it's actually at 7,  and 9 is 8. Etc

Comment: @Dave: Not every language. AWK for example indexes from 1 (0 has a special meaning of the entire array/list). There are also languages like Lua and Fortran that can index from **any number** because their arrays can be declared with a lower bound. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(array)

Comment: thanks for all help <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    ar.push( (i+1)' ===== '+arr[i]+'<br>');
}
```

Comment: ar.push( (i+1) + ' ===== '+arr[i]+'<br>');